# How to deploy Play! app to Google App Engine?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, playframework

**Via the Google app engine Eclipse plugin**

If I need to create a web app first, how do I convert the google web app to a play project?

If I need to create a play project first, how do I convert the play project to a google web app?

**Via command line and gae-module for play**

If I use the this command `play gae:deploy --gae=C:/appengine-sdk` I get Http connection timeouts. It is not my firewall, because I can deploy a hello world google web app via the google eclipse plugin.

I've tried all three methods, and I still can't deploy my play project to google app engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the Google App Engine plugin, but i managed to get it working through the command line. Apparently the problem was that although I disabled my firewall, it was still running a process that blocked the deployment without prompting. Fixed that

Comment: what is your play version ?? and if it is 2.0 please can you give me some details how exactly you deployed your app on gae.